# Spring ldaptemplate update group with large membership issue

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

I have issues updating groups in Active Directory with > 1500 members. It's only trying to modify the member attribute.

I have no issues updating groups with fewer members. I can also add a new group with many members.

However if its too large, update fails. I can try to update the large group to just one member and it still fails with the same error.

Code fails on the modifyAttributes line:

```
ModificationItem[] modList = 
nameContext.getDirContextAdapter().getModificationItems();

writeADTemplate.modifyAttributes(nameContext.getName(),modList);
```

StackTrace Below:

```
org.springframework.ldap.NameAlreadyBoundException: [LDAP: error code 68 - 
00000562: UpdErr: DSID-031A122A, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0
nested exception is javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [LDAP: error 
code 68 - 00000562: UpdErr: DSID-031A122A, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0
remaining name 'cn=Atlassian Users,ou=Groups'
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException
(LdapUtils.java:169)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext
(LdapTemplate.java:810)
at 
org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadWrite 
(LdapTemplate.java:802)
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.modifyAttributes
 (LdapTemplate.java:967)
 more ... 
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: [LDAP: error code 68 - 
00000562: UpdErr: DSID-031A122A, problem 6005 (ENTRY_EXISTS), data 0
remaining name 'cn=Atlassian Users,ou=Groups'
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(Unknown 
Source)
at 
com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(Unknown 
Source)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(Unknown Source)
at 
org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$19.executeWithContext 
(LdapTemplate.java:969)
at 
org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeWithContext 
(LdapTemplate.java:807)
... 88 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my real issue is that Active Directory will not return a multi value attribute like member if the values  > 1500. 
When I was getting the current group members it was return 0 values so my code was trying to add all the members back to the group.

Looks like I'll have to figure out how to use
DefaultIncrementalAttributesMapper to get all the members